# How do I split more than two views vertically in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can split views to get 2 views showing vertically on the right (e.g. Structure on top and Maven Projects on bottom). I'd like to see three views (or more) such as the Hierarchy, such that the Hierarchy view is in the middle and all three views are separated with splitters. Is this possible? I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have more than 2 views on the left or right side.

You can of course put one of the views on the left side below the "Project" view, or make the view floating (right click -> `Floating Mode`), or put the view on the very bottom (next to Event Log, for example)

Alternatively you can make some shortcuts for your most command maven commands, where they will be available from the Run/Debug configurations on the top bar, so that you can hide the maven view and then view Heirarchy and Structure on the right.